# How i can fix the problem with docker compose on mac m1?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

Good evening. Tried to use docker for the first time on m1 to launch laravel. Followed their official documentation, first step this, was ok

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

next step was this

```
cd example-app
 
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

and after i get error

```
compose is not a docker command
```

how can i fix thix?

Tried to find info, but nothing helped.

Comment: What version of Docker Desktop are you using?

Comment: latest — v4.14.0

Comment: Is _Preferences > General > Use Docker Compose V2_ enabled in your Docker desktop?